# Map of a region of Milky Way (Ra, Dec) with temperature

Tags: python, mapping, coordinates, histogram, astropy

I have to create a map of a region of Milky Way; (data collected with a radiotelescope).

I have files .txt with cooordinates **dec** and **ra**, and the correspondent **temperature** observed:

```
244.785416667;-13.5105555556;-2.96409416136
246.039166667;-13.5086111111;4.7494842185
247.292083333;-13.5066666667;4.85067698715
```

every file in .txt corresponds to a elevation (23,24,25,26,27,30).

I want something like this:

[image]

but I cant't find a way, in python, to plot it. I think I should use something like histo2D, but I can't figure it out how/where set the temperature's datas.
I've tryed with this code, but is wrong, (maybe also logically):

```
pp.figure(1)
pp.hist2d(ra,dec,bins=(20,5),range=((250,320),(-24,-16)), weights=temp)
pp.colorbar()
pp.show()
```

If you know even also the type of histo or of graphic I should use in this case, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of heatmap figure, I like to use `imshow` from matplotlib.

An example of some code using this could look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.add_subplot(111)

heat = ax.imshow(tempmat,
                 cmap=plt.cm.viridis,
                 interpolation='none')

# include a colorbar to show the temperature corresponding to each colour
curax = make_axes_locatable(plt..agca())
cbax = curax.append_axes('right', '5%', pad='3%')
fig.colorbar(heat, cax=cbax)

fig.savefig("temperature_heatmap.pdf")
# or instead of saving, just use fig.show()
```

Here, we have passed a 2D array `tempmat` to the imshow function. In your case, for a given .txt file, this would contain the temperature values at a fixed set of bins in RA and Dec. You could do this using numpy's [histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

# since your example shows semicomma-separated values
dat = np.loadtxt("filename.txt", delimiter=';')

# bin the data in a space of RA and Dec bins, with
# - RAbins = number of bins you want in RA
# - Decbins = number of bins you want in Dec
#   (alternatively, supply arrays of bin edges for uneven bin widths)
# - [0, 360] and [-90, 90] or your preferred range 
#   of RA and Dec to plot temperature bins for
# - weight counts by the temperature of each data point
tsums = np.histogram2d(dat[:, 1], dat[:, 0], 
                       bins=[RAbins, Decbins],
                       range=[[0, 360], [-90, 90]],
                       weights=dat[:, 2])

# here we repeat as above without the weighting, 
# so that we can find the average temperature in each bin
bincounts = np.histogram2d(dat[:, 1], dat[:, 0], 
                           bins=[RAbins, Decbins],
                           range=[[0, 360], [-90, 90]],
                           weights=dat[:, 2])

# divide the resulting 2d arrays to get bin temperatures
tempmat = tsums[0] / bincounts[0]
```

Here's an example I made with some random data:

[image]